# Why am I getting this Error in C# Compiler "Unassigned Local Variable"

Tags: c#, arrays, compiler-errors, duplicates, unassigned-variable

I am getting the following error. Use of unassigned local variable markduplicate. I don't understand why? This program finds a duplicate in an array. I been trying to figure it out and I feel like im so close. Thanks for the help.

```
using System;

class duplicate 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
    const int Array_Size = 5;
    int [] number = new int [Array_Size];
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++) 
    {
        Console.Write("Element " + i + ":    ");
        number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if (number[i] < 9 || number[i] > 101)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number between 10 - 100");
            number[i] = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    bool markduplicate;
    for (i = 0; i < Array_Size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Array_Size; j++) 
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                if (number[j] == number[i])
                {
                    markduplicate = true;
                }
            }

            if (markduplicate != true) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element " + i + "    " + number[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Because not all paths through the loop assign at value to `markduplicate`.  simply initialize it with `false`?

Comment: markDuplicate is not assignemd a value prior to entering the loop. Assign it an initial value of False and you should be fine.

Comment: This is an aside, but is there a reason you're declaring i outside of the scope of the loops?

Comment: Also, you might want to rework your loops a bit.   Suppose you have the numbers 1,1, and 1.  You will print out "Element 0 1" twice, then "Element 1 1" twice, then "Element 2 1" twice. I's declare `markduplicate` in the outer loop, and put a `break` statement after setting `markduplicate` in the inner loop. I'd move the printing to the outer loop too, and change the sense of the if clause.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the **exact** error message you're getting, and mark the line that's causing it with a comment. You have that specific information right in front of you; it's much easier if you provide it. :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is because the C#'s code analyzer detected that there are paths through you program when the `markduplicate`'s value would be referenced before any assignments to it are made. Specifically, this is going to happen during the very first iteration of the nested loop, when both `i` and `j` are zero: the `if (i != j)` block containing the assignment is not going to execute, so the value of the `markduplicate` is going to get retrieved in the very next `if` statement.

To fix this problem, change

```
bool markduplicate;
```

to

```
bool markduplicate = false;
```

in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler thinks it is possible for you to hit the `if (markduplicate != true)` line before `markduplicate` has been set.

If you think the compiler is wrong, give it a value when declaring e.g. `bool markduplicate = true;`. If you analyze and think the compiler is correct, adjust you code accordingly.

Also: `if (markduplicate != true)` is considered poor style. Use `if(!markduplicate)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared the boolean variable `markduplicate` but you haven't given it an initial value - the compiler doesn't know if it should be initially true or false.

In this case it's clear you want it to be initially false, so put this:

```
bool markduplicate = false;
```

it will now compiled.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `(i != j)` is false before it is true and therefore you are checking the value of your variable which has had nothing assigned to it.

You need to either assign a value to markduplicate at its declaration or you need to make sure that any path that leads to a conditional check on its value has a value assigned to it first.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign `markdefault` to either `true` or `false` in your declaration. Otherwise, if `number [j] != number [i]`, then `markdefault` will not be assigned and `if markduplicate != true` cannot be evaluated.